# Create hyperlink from path in python

Tags: python, csv, hyperlink

Kind of a noob question. Sorry for that.

I have a string path

`W:\documents\files`

Is it possible to create an hyperlink from that and store it in a csv so that when a click it in Excel it opens the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
from pathlib import Path
link = Path('W:\\documents\\files\\sample.txt').as_uri()
```

It should return "file:///W:/documents/files/sample.txt"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
import csv
with open('my_csv_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["file:///W:/documents/files"])
```

the csv module lets you read and write to csv files.  Adding `file:///` before your file path will let you link to it.  Note that this code will write the text to a csv file but it won't become a hyperlink until you put the cursor in front of it and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you said.

I think  maybe you want to write hyperlink path in csv.

That is just use "".

like this.
function("W:\documents\files")